# RDLC export not having page breaks as it does in pdf

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have an rdlc report when exporting to pdf having page breaks but same report when exporting to excel having no page breaks and all report data set I am getting as one with no page breaks. I need to have page breaks similar to how we get when it exceeds more than one page.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. It would be easier for people to help you if you could provide more data about the problem (exactly steps you do, examples etc.). If it's possible try to spend some time to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) .

Answer (score 0):

PDF is a print-ready format. That is why you already have page breaks.

Excel will give page breaks if you actually prompt the printer dialog by clicking on "Print" or by pressing CTRL+P. But that is done by first opening the file.

It is true that Excel can highlight pages in the sheet, but this will need some view settings, which cannot be done automatically with RDLC.

Another option is to generate the Excel file by code and not by RDLC. Then we can use a plugin like [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi) that would help you to configure the Excel file at will.